# Laravel include package view between header and footer of the page

Tags: laravel

I have created a Package in laravel and i am not able to include the package between header and footer of the page. Please find the code below,

```
$this->loadViewsFrom(__DIR__.'\views','details');
```

How to include the package between header and footer section of a website ?
Please help me to resolve the issue.

The package have the following structure as show below

```
--Root
  --packages
      --events
          --details
               --src
                   --assets
                   --Models
                   --Request
                   --Views
                 routes.php
                 DetailsServiceProvider.php
                 DetailsController.php
           composer.json
```

Answer (score 1):

In your [service provider](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/providers) you will register a view namespace using the code:

```
$this->loadViewsFrom(__DIR__.'\relative\path\from\service-provider','details');
```

Now you would be able to load files using `view('details::template-file')` which will look for the path `\relative\path\from\service-provider\template-file.blade` or by including them in other blade files: `@include('details::template-file')`